# Postgres server start fails - WANTED: netstat -ant|grep 5432 output explanation

Tags: server, ruby, postgresql

**INFO:** I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app. Hosting on Heroku with postgres. Tried running "heroku run rake db:migrate" as usual, but getting error "cannot connect,... check if something else is already running on port 5432".

Running sudo netstat -ant|grep 5432 yields the following output:

tcp4 0 0 127.0.0.1.5432 . LISTEN

tcp6 0 0 ::1.5432 . LISTEN

4d57a178eac394c1 stream 0 0 4d57a178edd97839 0 0 0 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

**QUESTION:** I'm not sure as to what this is telling me and how I can use the output to solve my Postgres/ port5432 problem. Any ideas? If there is something running other than my app, how can I stop it?

Thanks!!